# Share values betwen C++ to C# via CLR/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, c

before i need to say that I'm still not very familiarized with c ++.

i writed a project c++ that will share info with my c# project via CLR.
But the problem is, my c# project receive values  0. my follow example .

this is my main project c++ main.cpp that is at run time:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Runing..\n";
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(100);

        int t1 = rand()% 10 + 1;

        getvalue = t1;

        std::cout << "value: " << getvalue << std::endl;

    }


}
```

my main.h:

```
extern "C"  
{
    int getvalue = 0;
    __declspec(dllexport) int ReturnValue() {
        return getvalue;
    }

}
```

this is  my CLR project that will sent info to my C#:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace Lib {
    public ref class MyWrapper
    {
    public:
        MyWrapper()
        {

        }

        ~MyWrapper()
        {

        }

        int  getValue() {

            return ReturnValue();
        }



    };
}
```

my C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyWrapper p = new MyWrapper();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value -> " + p.getValue());
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }
}
```

and result is this, i put a image to be more clear:
link: https://imgur.com/54iMvFf

Comment: They're separate processes running in completely different address spaces.  The `getvalue` in the C++ process is totally different from the one loaded into the C# process.

Comment: what you sugest?

Comment: There are too many unknowns here, especially pertaining to the goal (not to be confused with any specific mechanism, since this one didn't work), and that makes it too broad a question for this format.

Comment: When you run C# program, its `Main` is executed, but `main` in C is not executed. So the value is always zero. If you run your C program, it's `main` is executed, but then the C# part is not executed. If you run both of them, they are executed separately - simply said they don't see each other. More technically said, as @madreflection wrote, they run in a separate processes.